# New graphics card reported as "standard VGA display adapter"

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation, nvidia-graphics-card

After installing a new hard drive on my Sony vpccw16fs laptop, I installed Windows 7.  I installed drivers from a Driver Pack Solution saved from my old hard drive.  My system now only reports a "standard VGA display adapter", instead of my Nvidia GeForce GT 230M graphics card.

Nvidia's site will scan my computer and find the GT 230M but when I down load and install the driver I get an error message "graphics driver could not find graphics hardware".  I downloaded the driver from Sony's sight and on running the installation program will only install the audio driver.  I'm 2 days into this and have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Exactly which driver did you download from Sony?

Comment: The file name is EP0000208510.exe.  The Sony site didn't give a driver number it only listed the audio driver, the video driver was grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install a new driver you have to uninstall any previously installed version. In case you cant uninstall the previous version, try to do a clean install of windows.

Something about Sony:

Sony provides their own OEM Nvidia driver for some laptop models, so the only way to get the right driver is from their support site. On my vccw14fx the 2009 driver model is working fine but if I update with the 2010 version I get the blue screen during Skype video calls. There are some modified ini files for the official nvidia driver, ask google about them. I haven't tried them yet but I plan to with a clean install of windows 8.

Comment: Update: Although Sony doesn't give any support for Windows 8 on vccw14fx laptops, I managed to get the x64 version of windows 8 installed using the nvidia windows 7 driver from sony. Didn't have to use any modified ini files. Everything works fine.